# How to backup SVN repository from one server to another

Tags: backup, svn

We have installed subversion 1.6 and SVN client (TortoiseSVN 1.5). We've created a repository on the server which is active now, and we are going to set up a new repository on another server to replicate the master repository. Can anyone provide the steps on how to achieve this?

We saw a few configuration processes like svnsync, but those are not understandable to new users.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a one-time operation (as opposed to an attempt to keep the two servers in-sync continuously), that's easy.

On the old server:

```
svnadmin dump /path/to/old_repo > dump.svn
```

Compress and copy at your discretion. Look at the help output for further options (like incremental dumps, limiting the dump to certain revision ranges etc.) Then, on the new server:

```
svnadmin load /path/to/new_repo < dump.svn
```

That should be it. (Unless the dump format changed between 1.6 and 1.8, which I don't know about; you might want to test this with a *small* repo beforehand.)

Answer (score 0):

1. Why do you use outdated and unsupported versions of the software? Subversion 1.6 is not supported since the release of 1.8 version. There is no reason to stay with these outdated releases, especially if you are new to Subversion.
2. Read [SVNBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.replication). I'm pointing you to SVNBook because your question is too broad to answer and the chapter I've specified is a must-read for you. Read SVNBook!

Comment: There are actually a number of perfectly good reasons why people might be using old software. Corporate environments, for example, where a migration to a newer version might affect *thousands* of systems and does cost real money, are usually slow to jump to new versions. (That's one of the reasons why "release early, release often" doesn't cut it in the corporate environs.)

Comment: @DevSolar Thanks for your input. Apache Subversion development does not follow "release early, release often" paradigm and those versions user3441238 are way too~ outdated.

Comment: Nevertheless we've been stuck with 1.6 in our company until quite recently, ourselves. The version worked "good enough", so quite frankly they were not "too outdated".